# 504 Time-out when deploying node.js app to Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase-hosting

I am working on this app that is running as wxpected on localhost but once deployed to firebase hosting it throw this error

> 504 Gateway Time-out

The function save a file to the disk and I am afraid that a disk is not available when deploying, just like heroku when you restart the dynos.

```
app.get('/api', (request, response) => {
  var filename = Date.now() + '.jpg'
  webshot( url ,'public/' + filename , options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        response.send(filename);
    }
  });
})
```

Is that the reason I am getting the error? or it could be something else? Is it possible to store files on a node.js app once deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions have a [read-only file system](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) except for `/tmp` which is backed by the memory of your function.

[1:30 of this Firecast](https://youtu.be/2mjfI0FYP7Y?t=90) has a good example of writing to `/tmp`.

```
import * as os from 'os';
const tmp = os.tmpdir();
```

If you want to persist files you should look at using [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions).

Comment: I am looking to save the image to the disk for a very short period of time, just so I can upload it to imgur, gcloud is too much for this situation

Comment: That's generally what `/tmp` is used for.